# Meteor 1.6.1 + renderToNodeStream = Browser not loading the stream

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I tried to replace `renderToString` with `renderToNodeStream` in my React SSR.
The browser ended up stuck waiting for the stream to start (stuck in loading, but nothing ever arrived).

I have Helmet, styled-components, and node-cache on the server-side logic.
After removing all of them, leaving just the bare essentials

```
onPageLoad(sink => {


    let preloadedData = {}

    let visitorGeoDetails = undefined;



    let ip = dummyIP["HK"];



    visitorGeoDetails = geoip.lookup(ip);

    visitorGeoDetails.ip = ip;





    console.info(`rendering page on server for ${ip}...`);




    const setPreloadedContent = (key, value) => {
        preloadedData[key] = value;
    }

    sink.renderIntoElementById("react-app", renderToNodeStream(
      <App target="server" location={sink.request.url.path} visitorGeoDetails={visitorGeoDetails} setPreloadedContent={setPreloadedContent} />));


    preloadedData['visitorGeoDetails'] = visitorGeoDetails;



    sink.appendToBody(`
        <script>
          window.__PRELOADED_DATA__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedData)};
        </script>
      `);

  });
```

The problem still remains.

Is there any other thing I need to do when switching over to `renderToNodeStream` ?

PS: I see the server ran through the React Components (and if there were any warnings from propTypes, they also showed up in the server terminal console log when a browser try to access the site).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `react` along with other libraries like `redux` or `react-router` then you should wrap your `App` component with `Provider`/`StaticRouter`.

I went into same issue when I forgot to wrap my `App` component.

And also `renderToNodeStream` call must end with `.pipe(res)`.

So, you should do something like below.

```
renderToNodeStream(
     <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
          <Provider store={store}>
              <Routes />
          </Provider>
    </StaticRouter>
).pipe(res) // res -> express.js res object
```

If you want some working example of SSR, you can check out my [repository](https://github.com/leejh3224/Do-Server-Side-Rendering/blob/master/packages/router-redux-ssr/src/serverRender.jsx)